# How could I format the date inside the `kendo-datepicker` input using my own pipe in Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker, pipe

How could I format the date inside the `kendo-datepicker` input using my own pipe in Angular?

E.g. I can apply my own pipe to a date inside the `kendo-grid-column` in the following way:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="dueDate" [title]="'titles.dueDate' | translate">
   <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      {{dataItem.dueDate | localizedDate }}
   </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Now I want to do something similar in the `kendo-datepicker`. Something like:

```
<kendo-datepicker formControlName="theDate">
   <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      {{dataItem.theDate | localizedDate }}
   </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

I found [these](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/templates/) templates, but I was not able to use any of them to achieve the desired result. The desired result is that the value shown in the input of the `kendo-datepicker` will be a date formatted by my pipe.

I am aware of the `format` attribute. But it is not what I want, since it is static and I do not want to duplicate the logic of the date formatting (what my custom pipe is doing) across the project.

Comment: The problem is, the datePicker isn't simply displaying as a grid. It has to format the date you pick too. So the component should use your custom pipe as formatter. Seems to be a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this:

```
    <div class="example-config">
        Selected value is: {{value | kendoDate:'hh:mm:ss a'}}
    </div>
    <div class="example-wrapper" style="min-height: 400px">
        <p>Select a time value:</p>
        <kendo-timepicker
            [(value)]="value"
        ></kendo-timepicker>
    </div>
```